# mysql_select_db( not selecting database

Tags: php, mysql

I am experiencing a problem with `mysql_select_db()` function not selecting the right database . My code is as follows:

```
    global $file_count;


    $conlivedata = mysql_pconnect("localhost","*****","*****");
        if (!$conlivedata) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $con = mysql_pconnect("***************","*****","*****");
    if (!$con) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysql_select_db("csv_db", $con)or die("A MySQL error has occurred.Your Query: Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE EmailAddr <> ' ' ORDER BY `EmailAddr`") or die("<br/>A MySQL Query error has occurred.Your Query: Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
        $Email = $row['EmailAddr'];
        if ($Email != NULL ){
            mysql_select_db("foswood_db", $conlivedata) or die("<br/>A MySQL error has occurred Slecting Database.<br />Your Query: <br/> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
            $liveresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pledges WHERE EmailAddr = '$Email'") or die("<br/>A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: <br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
            if(mysql_result($liveresult, 0) ) echo ': **Voted**';;
            mysql_select_db("csv_db", $con) or die("<br/>A MySQL error has occurred Slecting Database.<br />Your Query: <br /> Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }

    mysql_close($con);
    mysql_close($conlivedata);
```

I get the error message:

```
A MySQL error has occurred.
Your Query:
Error: (1146) Table 'csv_db.pledges' doesn't exist
```

has anyone any idea why please?

Comment: I guess you already have your answer.

Comment: check your table name again and also why you declared mysql_select_db 2 times ?

Comment: @DevangRathod There are two different connections.

Comment: I think it's because: Table 'csv_db.pledges' doesn't exist

Comment: Yes the two databases one on each connection.

Comment: foswood_db.pledges exits and csv_db.tbl_name exists on different connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the database used for the query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` WHERE EmailAddr <> ' ' ORDER BY `EmailAddr`", **$con**) ...
```

Comment: I had to strangely rewrite teh code with the to connections opening first. This fixed the issue.